# Redux store updated in wrong way

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm developing a React Web App and using Redux for storing values. However I'm having hard times with updating the store as I wanted.

So I'm fetching posts with API call and I let my users to rate the posts. There is no problem at executing action, server gets updated as I expect. This is my redux store =>

[image: redux-store]

and I have `rated_by` section in post which shows user and its rate value=>

[image: rated_by]

What I want is after the user rates a post, the store should be updated by the rate action's payload.(it sends `post id` and `rate value`)

**reducer.js**

```
const initialState = {
    posts: [],
}

export default function(state = initialState, action){
    switch(action.type) {
        case RATE_POST:
            return {
                ...state,
                [state.posts.filter(post => post.id === action.postId)]: post(state[state.posts.filter(post => post.id === action.postId)], action)
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}

const post = (state={}, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case RATE_POST:
            const { postId, sRate } = action
            return {
                ...state,
                rate: sRate,
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

After user rated a post, store gets updated like that =>

[image: updated-store]

How should I re-write my reducer to work properly?

Comment: please add a codesandbox for reviewing your code, there's code missing here in the OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long research I found out that `ids` should be different in each child component. So I changed the code like below =>

```
 return(
    <fieldset className="rate-rating" >
        <input type="button" onClick={onClick} id={"star5"+props.post.id} name="rate-rate-rating" value="5" /><label className = "full" htmlFor={"star5"+props.post.id}></label>
        <input type="button" onClick={onClick} id={"star4half"+props.post.id} name="rate-rating" value="4.5" /><label className="half" htmlFor={"star4half"+props.post.id} ></label>
        <input type="button" onClick={onClick} id={"star4"+props.post.id} name="rate-rating" value="4" /><label className = "full" htmlFor={"star4"+props.post.id} ></label>
        <input type="button" onClick={onClick} id={"star3half"+props.post.id} name="rate-rating" value="3.5" /><label className="half" htmlFor={"star3half"+props.post.id} ></label>
        <input type="button" onClick={onClick} id={"star3"+props.post.id} name="rate-rating" value="3" /><label className = "full" htmlFor={"star3"+props.post.id} ></label>
        <input type="button" onClick={onClick} id={"star2half"+props.post.id} name="rate-rating" value="2.5" /><label className="half" htmlFor={"star2half"+props.post.id} ></label>
        <input type="button" onClick={onClick} id={"star2"+props.post.id} name="rate-rating" value="2" /><label className = "full" htmlFor={"star2"+props.post.id} ></label>
        <input type="button" onClick={onClick} id={"star1half"+props.post.id} name="rate-rating" value="1.5" /><label className="half" htmlFor={"star1half"+props.post.id} ></label>
        <input type="button" onClick={onClick} id={"star1"+props.post.id} name="rate-rating" value="1" /><label className = "full" htmlFor={"star1"+props.post.id} ></label>
        <input type="button" onClick={onClick} id={"starhalf"+props.post.id} name="rate-rating" value="0.5" /><label className="half" htmlFor={"starhalf"+props.post.id}></label>
    </fieldset>
)
```